# Why does this OCaml expression have the following type?

Tags: types, ocaml

The expression is `f x y = 1 + (x 1) + (y 1)` which has a type of `(int->int)->(int->int)->int`.  I don't understand how it has that type.  why isn't it `int->int`?

Answer (score 3):

Since you have function applications (x 1) and (y 1). x and y are treated like functions that take an int argument and return an int.

So x is type (int -> int) and y is type (int -> int).
1 is applied on both x and y. So if 1 is applied on something that is type (int -> int) you get something that is type int. So your whole function returns 1 + int + int which is basically int.

Answer (score 3):

When OCaml infers the type of expression

```
let f x y = 1 + (x 1) + (y 1)
```

It will think something like this:

1. Since `(+)` has type `int -> int`, expression `(x 1)` should have type `int`, as it occurs on the right hand side of `+`.
2. Since `x 1` should evaluate to `int` and it is an application, it should have type `_ -> int`. As `1` is an `int` literal, it has type `int -> int`.
3. Using the same logic we can infer, that `y` also has type `int -> int`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(x 1)` requires x to be a function of type `int -> 'a`. Similarly for `(y 1)`. The rest follows from this.

Answer (score 2):

```
let f x y = 1 + (x 1) + (y 1)
```

1. you have `(x 1)`, so x must be a function
2. you have `1 + (x 1)`, so `(x 1)` must return an int, also 1 is int, so `x: int -> int <fun>`
3. using the same induction as above, `y: int -> int <fun>`
4. you have `f x y`, so f is a function, we already know what type x and y is and also know the right handside of `=` must be an int, so `f: (int -> int) -> (int -> int) -> int`